# Left space in Toolbar with SearchView android studio

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, searchview

I'm trying to add a simple `SearchView` to the toolbar in my app. Everything it's working fine expect for the layout.

There is this "space" between the `NavigationDrawer` icon and the `SearchView`.
If I set a title the space is filled with that string, otherwise is empty.

**Empty string:**

[image]

**With a string in title:**

[image]

How do I remove that annoying empty space?

**Edit:**

I'm using as base code the `NavigationDrawer` example from Android Studio

**main.xml**

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    </menu>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="ga.musicforyou.musicforyou.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemTextColor="#FFF"
        app:itemIconTint="#FFF"

        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show the layout code?

Comment: Yes, I've edited my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Toolbar extends from FrameLayout and you can put views inside it. Like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/primary_color">

<SearchView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Edit: You put it inside the layout as a menu. It always will be on the right side of the toolbar, because it is a menu. If you want to have a more direct control over views inside a toolbar, just put it there as I did show you.

Comment: Definetly the right answer! Can you help with the next step? How do I set a OnQueryTextListener to the SearchView now?

Before it was working with:
 SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener;
        MenuItem searchItem  = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

Comment: @GregoryWullimann It now should behave like a normal view inside an activity, so just "findViewById" in the activity.

Comment: Thanks, I had a small problem between android.widget.SearchView and android.support.v7.widget.SearchView, seems to be working now.

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: I have set actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true). Your solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have set `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` in code. So only adding `SearchView` in the toolbar didn't work for me and there is some extra space between Navigation Back and `SearchView`. I don't have Title in `Toolbar`. So I customized whole toolbar like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" // If parent layout is RelativeLayout
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp" // This is important,
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp" // Otherwise there will be extra space on Left Side
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivNavBack"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:background="@drawable/your_drawable" // Custom background (optional), if you want to have a press effect
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_nav_back" /> // You can set icon of your choice here

            <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:queryHint="@string/search_view_hint"
                app:queryHint="@string/search_view_hint" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

...& in your Activity:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
SearchView  searchView = (SearchView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.searchView);
searchView.onActionViewExpanded(); // Expands searchView by default
// If this is not set, then you will see default search icon and you have to click it to expand SearchView.
```

Now no need to set `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` in code. Just handle click event of `ivNavBack` for it.

[image]