# SearchView in action bar is shifted to right

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I added SearchView to my action bar, but it appears to be shifted to right if there is back button (or drawer toggle) in action bar.

main_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:title="123"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package org.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

If setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false):
[image]

If setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true):
[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514614/left-space-in-toolbar-with-searchview-android-studio